# How to make bot say if it atleast includes rather than explicitly saying !*example*

Tags: javascript, discord

I am making a Discord Bot that separates messages into categories. How can I change it so the message doesn't have to explicitly include !*example* and rather say the category if the message at least includes it?

For example

```js
bot.on('message' , msg=>{
    if(msg.content === "!part-installations"){
        msg.reply("Re Category: Part Installations");
    }
})
```

The following code only makes the bot state the category if it specifically states !part-installations with no other words. How can I modify the code so that it can still state the category if it at least has for example !part-installations?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use a regex, which just checks to see if msg.content contains your substring.

```
if (/!part-installations/gi.test(msg.content)) { }
```

You could also use .indexOf and if the value is > -1, the substring is in msg.content:

```
if (msg.content.indexOf('!part-installations') > -1) { }
```